# How to install previous/older version of octave in buster?

Tags: software-installation, raspbian-buster, packages

Currently Octave version 4.4.1 is available. It always crashes while start. I am trying to install an older version of octave but I can not find any older packages in the repo and the sources are taking a very long time to compile. How am I supposed to get a older version of octave?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Octave is not working in raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/104281/octave-is-not-working-in-raspbian)

Comment: Not actually. Because I don't want to use that version anymore. If someone finds a solution for either I am happy

Comment: Plenty of posts on installing old pacakge versions, see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90374/how-to-install-libdb4-8-on-jessie and https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24086/raspbian-download-sources-of-older-packages.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the syntax is

```
apt-get install octave=4.0.3
```

Or whatever version you want to install. Don't hold your breath though: it will only work if the package for that version actually exists in the pool, and all its dependencies are also available.

In Debian, old packages are available via https://snapshot.debian.org/. You can add a snapshot to your `sources.list` and install package versions from that snapshot, being sure that all dependencies are there. I'm not aware of such an archive for Raspbian though.

Installing Debian `armhf` packages on a Raspberry is possible (including Octave), but this is not a decision that should be taken lightly. There's a lot of potential to screw up your system by accidentally overwriting a Raspbian package with a Debian one which may be incompatible.

Considering the questions you have asked earlier, my advice is to back up important files and restart from scratch. Chances are, you will get the latest Octave working.